# Menu closes when you scroll down on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am currently trying to make the new website for my school but I am having some problems with the responsive menu. Basically when I open the menu on a mobile device some of the links do not appear on the page as there are too many. When I try to scroll down through the list of links the menu just closes. I don't know what to do to solve the problem cos I've got no idea what's even causing it. Please help!
Any ideas?

You can see the page [here](https://poison-pen-swells.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: post least a snippet code code

Answer (score 0):

First Change the script order in your website. `Jquery` should be at top of all the remaining scripts. In your website it's different. See the below image.
[image]

and at the same time you are using `ksmenu.js` twice.

And for the issue you are asking is there is a script to hide menu on resize. Please see the below image.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if theres a script to hide the menu on resize. I didn´t write the JS. The menu worked fine when I tested it in Codepen but stops working when all the other content is included